# Obtaining Hamiltonian Matrix from Operators (Dirac Notation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, operator-theory, orthonormal

To give some context, this question stems from the physical scenario of 6 ions forming a molecule, where each ion is a "site" in which a single electron is able to hop between ions. Consider a crystal lattice with periodic boundary conditions as an analogue. Periodic boundary conditions are relevant here where the basis vector $|e_j\rangle$ represents the electron being present on the $j^{th}$ ion, where $j = 1,2,3,4,5,6$. Then to enforce periodicity, $|e_j\rangle = |e_{j\pm 6}\rangle$.

The state of the system is given as $$|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^{6}a_j|e_j\rangle$$ where $$\sum_{j=1}^{6}|a_j|^2 = 1$$

Now for the math:

I have kinetic and potential operators for the single electron as:

$$\hat{\mathcal{K}} = (-f) \sum_{j=1}^{6}(|e_j\rangle\langle e_{j+1}| + |e_{j+1}\rangle\langle e_j|) + (-f')\sum_{j=1}^{3}(|e_j\rangle\langle e_{j+3}| + |e_{j+3}\rangle\langle e_j|)$$

$$\hat{\mathcal{V}} = \sum_{j=1}^{6}\varepsilon_j |e_j\rangle\langle e_j|$$

respectively. Then, the Hamiltonian, $\hat{\mathcal{H}}$ should be a sum of these two operators, $\hat{\mathcal{H}} = \hat{\mathcal{T}}+\hat{\mathcal{V}}$.

I don't understand how to compute the sums within these operators in order to form a matrix.

More specifically, how do I approach the sums:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{6}(|e_j\rangle\langle e_{j+1}| + |e_{j+1}\rangle\langle e_j|) $$$$\sum_{j=1}^{3}(|e_j\rangle\langle e_{j+3}| + |e_{j+3}\rangle\langle e_j|)$$

For a two ion molecule, we have that $|e_j\rangle\langle e_{j+1}| = |e_1\rangle\langle e_{2}|$ for $j=1$. This yields:

$$|e_1\rangle\langle e_2| = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and similarly, 
$$|e_2\rangle\langle e_1| = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Do I need to compute the same steps above for each $j$ in the 6 ion case, and add the resulting 6 x 6 matrices which arise? Or is there an easier way to obtain the result of these sums?

Then finally, once I reduce $\hat{\mathcal{K}}$ and $\hat{\mathcal{V}}$ down to three matrices, do I just add them up? I feel that the second sum in $\hat{\mathcal{K}}$, which only goes from $j = 1,2,3$ will not allow me to add them easily..

Comment: Draw the brackets around the matrix and start adding the components part by part.  For instance when $j=1$ in $\sum_{j=1}^{6}(|e_j\rangle\langle e_{j+1}| + |e_{j+1}\rangle\langle e_j|)$ you have a $1$ in the first row, second column and another $1$ in the second row, first column.  Add the other terms step by step and then complete the matrix with $0$'s.  Note that after you've done $j=1$ and $j=2$, you'll probably see the pattern and will be able to just add the rest in (take care with the $j=6$ part though: remember that $|e_7\rangle  = |e_1\rangle$).

Comment: I am sensing a pattern here as I am trying to work through what you suggest. As I am working with orthonormal bases, it seems I am going to end up with a matrix of diagonal 1's just above and below the true diagonal of the matrix, similar to the form of a matrix for a raising or lowering operator. For the second sum in $\hat{\mathcal{K}}$ where $j$ only goes to 3, I now think I'll end up with another 6x6 matrix, since the vectors I'm working with all contain 6 elements. Is this correct?

Comment: Almost.  Don't forget the $j=6$ part of the first sum.  Yes the second sum will also give you a $6\times 6$ matrix.

Comment: Hm, so with periodicity, it appears I'll obtain 1's in the top right and bottom left of my matrix. Sorry to be repetitive, but once each matrix is obtained, am I able to multiply my constants $f, f', \varepsilon_j$ into each respective matrix and just perform matrix addition to obtain the Hamiltonian?

Comment: That is correct.